# Find $x $- coordinates of the vertical tangent lines of a function.

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

The function $6+(x^3)y = x(y^2)$ has vertical tangent lines. 
How do you find the functions of these lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the derivative of the function,we obtain

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{3x^2-y^2}{2xy-x^3} $$ which the is slope of the tangent.

We know that when the tangent is vertical, its slope is $\infty$. Hence, inorder to obtain points where the slope is  $\infty$, just equate the denominator to zero.
$$2xy-x^3=0$$ Now, you will get an expression for $y$ in terms of $x$. Substitute them in the first equation and obtain the co-ordinates of the required points. The equation of the tangents can easily be found.

Comment: I got stuck on the algebra trying to solve for y in order to plug it in to the final expression to solve for x. Is this necessary? How can I solve the original equation for either variable in order to finish the problem?

Comment: It is not necessary to solve for $y$. Finding $x$ would be enough. As the tangent is vertical, It's equation would be of the form $x=x_0$, exactly as @dantopa points out in the answer below. Here, $x_0$ is the co-ordinate at the point where the tangent is drawn.

Comment: You will get $y=+\frac{x}{\sqrt 2}$ and $-\frac{x}{\sqrt 2}$ from the expression $2xy-x^3=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Standard answer from calculus. If the vertical line is at $x_{0}$, the equation is: $x = x_{0}$.

[image]

A more straightforward example is $$y^{2} = x.$$ The tangent line is $x=0$.